# How to make two requests using the same socket?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tcp, keep-alive

This code makes two requests.  However, they use different sockets.  How can I configure the `Server` or request `Agent` in order for both requests to use the same socket?

```
import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, Agent, request } from 'node:http';
import { Socket } from 'node:net';

console.log('\n\n');

let server = new Server({ keepAlive: true});
server.addListener('request', (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {

    console.log('Server_request');
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log('IncomingMessage.socket.remotePort', req.socket.remotePort);

    let data = '';

    req.addListener('data', (chunk: string) => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_data');
        data = data + chunk;
    })

    req.addListener('close', () => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_close');
    });

    req.addListener('end', () => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_end');
        res.end('');
    });
})

server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");

server.addListener('close', () => console.log('sever_close'));

server.addListener('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    // "This event is emitted when a new TCP stream is established (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-connection)." 
    socket.addListener('close', () => console.log('Socket_close'));
    console.log("Socket.localPort", socket.localPort);
    console.log("Socket.remotePort", socket.remotePort);
})

let agent = new Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 1});

let req0 = request(
    { 
        agent: agent,
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST'
    }, (res:IncomingMessage)=>{
        console.log(res.headers);
    });

req0.end("0");

let req1 = request(
    {
        agent: agent,
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST'
    }, (res:IncomingMessage)=>{ 
        console.log(res.headers);
    });

req1.end("1");
```

This is a possible result:

```
Socket.localPort 3000
Socket.remotePort 38880
Server_request
{
  host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '1'
}
IncomingMessage.socket.remotePort 38880
IncomingMessage_data
IncomingMessage_end
IncomingMessage_close
{
  date: 'Sun, 21 May 2023 18:53:56 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
  'content-length': '0'
}
Socket_close
Socket.localPort 3000
Socket.remotePort 34564
Server_request
{
  host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '1'
}
IncomingMessage.socket.remotePort 34564
IncomingMessage_data
IncomingMessage_end
IncomingMessage_close
{
  date: 'Sun, 21 May 2023 18:54:01 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
  'content-length': '0'
}
Socket_close
```

Comment: Why, what would be the point?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please let me know why it is pointless.  Thanks.

Comment: @stackhatter no, no. You are trying to do something without a good reason to do it. That's enough reason not do it. Sockets are a low level network construct and it is rarely a good idea to deal with them directly. Especially when you have a library that deals with all the nasty details for you. This looks like XY problem. So the question is: what are you trying to achieve, really? Why do you even care?

Comment: @freakish  I don't think it is the XY problem, because the problem that I posted was specifically the problem I was trying to solve.  I solved it - I posted the solution.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError HTTP *does* work that way out of the box.

Comment: This code doesn't make any requests at all. It receives them. And [tag:tcp-keepalive] has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user207421  Thank you for for making the correction to the tcp-keepalive tag - I apparently wasn't paying attention.

I have been contemplating what you said about the code not making "any request at all" for several months now.  It's still not clear to me what you mean.  How is it that the code does not make any requests at all?  There are a couple of calls using the `request` function, for example.

Comment: @freakish I only recently figured out why I needed to understand this.  Check out my post on retro-causality in the Data Science stack exchange.

Comment: @stackhatter If `req0.end("0")` sends the request, I am mistaken about that.

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" here is to drain the response; this allows for the subsequent request to proceed using the same socket before it closes (i.e., the res.resume();):

```
import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, Agent, request } from 'node:http';
import { Socket } from 'node:net';

console.log('\n\n');

let server = new Server({ keepAlive: true, keepAliveTimeout: 4000 });

server.addListener('request', (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {

    console.log('Server_request');
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log('IncomingMessage.socket.remotePort', req.socket.remotePort);

    let data = '';

    req.addListener('data', (chunk: string) => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_data');
        data = data + chunk;
    });

    req.addListener('close', () => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_close');
    });

    req.addListener('end', () => {
        console.log('IncomingMessage_end');
        res.end('');
    });
});

server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");

server.addListener('close', () => console.log('Server_close'));

server.addListener('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    // "This event is emitted when a new TCP stream is established (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-connection)." 
    socket.addListener('close', () => console.log('Socket_close'));
    console.log("Socket.localPort", socket.localPort);
    console.log("Socket.remotePort", socket.remotePort);
})

let agent = new Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 1, timeout: 2000 });

// The agent will keep the socket open for 2 seconds.
let req0 = request(
    {
        agent: agent,
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST'
    }, (res: IncomingMessage) => {
        console.log(res.headers);
        res.resume();
    });

req0.end("0");

// The Socket is still open; hence, make another request using the same destination port number (i.e., the same socket).
let req1 = request(
    {
        agent: agent,
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'POST'
    }, (res: IncomingMessage) => {
        console.log(res.headers);
        res.resume();
        // Drain the Readable.
    });

req1.end("1");


setTimeout(() => {
    // Use the same agent to make another request.
    // The Socket has been closed (> 2000ms); hence, this request will likely have a different destination port number (i.e., a new Socket).
    let req2 = request(
        {
            agent: agent,
            hostname: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 3000,
            path: '/',
            method: 'POST'
        }, (res: IncomingMessage) => {
            console.log(res.headers);
            res.resume();
            // Drain the Readable.
        });

    req2.end("2");
}, 5000);
```